# How to fill Dropdown list from Database at the time of editing row in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to show data in dropdown list from database at the time of i edit row. Drop down list is placed in `<EditItemTemplate>` how to access this dropdown list in code file..

```
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Group of Broker">
        <itemtemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblGroupofBroker" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("groupofbroker")%>'></asp:Label>
        </itemtemplate>
        <edititemtemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroupofBroker" runat="server" DataTextField='<%# Eval("groupofbroker") %>'> </asp:DropDownList>
        </edititemtemplate>
        <itemstyle width="30px" />
        <footertemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>`
        </footertemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Plese Help ME how to access this drop down list in code file to fill data from database

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle `gridview_RowEditing` event

```
protected void gridview_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
    GridViewRow row = gvAllClients.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];

       // Change the row state
    DropDownList ddlDataType = (DropDownList)(row.FindControl("ddlDataTypeAll"));
     //ddlDataType.DataSource = <datasocurce>;
     //ddlDataType.DataBind(); 


    }
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: I ran in to the same thing. Any solution??